# Is it possible to do if-else checks in Ansible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

Currently, my spot EC2 provisioning play looks like this:

```
- name: Provisioning Spot instaces
  ec2:
    spot_price: 0.50
    spot_wait_timeout: 300
    assign_public_ip: no
    aws_access_key: "{{ aws_id }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ aws_key }}"
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    image: "{{ image_instance }}"
    instance_type: "{{ large_instance }}"
    key_name: "{{ ssh_keyname }}"
    count: 3
    state: present
    group_id: "{{ cypher_priv_sg }}"
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ private_subnet_id }}"
    wait: true
    instance_tags:
      Name: Cypher-Worker
    #delete_on_termination: yes
  register: ec2
```

So, is it possible to do the following:

While provisioning a (spot)EC2 instance, I want to check incrementally (like (40%. 50%, 60%, 70% .. )) And if all fails, then create an on-demand instance. **How do I do this?**

Can I make use of the [Blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) feature here?  If yes, then how?

Comment: Check what incrementally?

Comment: @MattSchuchard The `spot_price` value

Comment: Can you use some kind of `async/poll/register` and/or `begin/rescue` to do this? I am speaking theoretically here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Yeah, there is the [Blocks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_blocks.html) feature, but it doesn't take more than two `rescue` blocks. So, there's that :(

Answer (score 0):

Example:

```
shell: /some/command
register: result
when: ( result is not defined ) or ( result.rc != 0 )
with_items:
  - 40
  - 50
  - 60
  - 70
  - 100 # on-demand
```

This will run the task with all listed items until it is successful with one of them.

**UPD:** This is example for `shell` module, I don't know `ec2` module output structure, do not use it. For `shell` module it works fine. Why the downvotes?

Comment: Getting this error: `The error was: error while evaluating conditional (( ec2 is not defined ) or ( ec2.rc != 0 )): 'dict object' has no attribute 'rc'`

Comment: @Dawny33 for ec2 module you should use apropriate check for it's output structure. I posted example for shell module. And you should check registered variable, not module itself.

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 - name: Create ec2 instance
   ec2:
    key_name: "{{ key }}"
    group: "{{ group }}"
    instance_type: "{{ itype }}"
    image: "{{ image }}"
    region: "{{ region }}"
    wait: yes
    wait_timeout: 500
    volumes:
     - device_name: /dev/xvda
       volume_type: "{{ voltype }}"
       volume_size: "{{ volsize }}"
    monitoring: no
    vpc_subnet_id: "{{ subnetid }}"
   register: system

 - name: Wait for ssh
   wait_for: host={{ item.public_ip }} port=22 state=started
   with_items:
    - "{{ system.instances }}"

 - name: Name the new instance
   ec2_tag: resource={{ item.id }} region=eu-central-1 state=present
   args:
    tags:
     Name: "{{ name }}"
   with_items:
    - "{{ system.instances }}"
```

You (try to) create your instance and store its facts in `system`. If you need to check whether `system` actually contains what you need, you can simply add `when: system.instances.id[0] is defined`, or go even further - by checking whether your new instance is accessible on port 22, as in the above example.

You can use those conditional checks for another tasks, implementing a if-not logic - if the instance creation failed and it's not accessible by ssh, create an on-demand instance.

```
 - name: Wait for ssh
   wait_for: host={{ item.public_ip }} port=22 state=started
   with_items:
    - "{{ system.instances }}"
   register: result
```

Next step:

```
   when: '"ERROR" in result'
```